# How to call a function in a package

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, sys-refcursor

I'm doing the following but it doesnt work

```
select package_name.function_name(param,param) from dual
```

I'm calling a function that returns a cursor so im guessing `"from dual"` is the problem

is there another way of doing it?

Comment: What does 'it doesn't work' mean - what error do you get? And how is your 'cursor' defined in the package specification? Selecting from dual should work if it's a `sys_refcursor` and the function doesn't have any unpleasant side-effects...

Comment: I guess this question is related to your earlier one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613973/returned-ref-cursor-not-supported  Don't post you questions on the same topic.  If you don't get a satisfactory answer immediately edit your question to give more details.

Comment: For me, the question was my answer. I learned you call functions in Oracle via SELECT, not like stored procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean a Ref Cursor.  This is a PL/SQL construct which acts as a pointer to a set of records returned by a query.  This means it has to be interpreted by the client which runs the query.  For instance, we can map a Ref Cursor to a JDBC or ODBC ResultSet.

There is certainly nothing wrong with your basic statement.  Here is a function similar to your own:

```
SQL> desc get_emps
FUNCTION get_emps RETURNS REF CURSOR
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 P_DNO                          NUMBER(2)               IN
 P_SORT_COL                     VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT
 P_ASC_DESC                     VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT

SQL>
```

I can easily call this in a wider PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> declare
  2      rc sys_refcursor;
  3  begin
  4      rc := get_emps(50);
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

However, SQL*PLus can handle CURSOR constructs natively:

```
SQL> select get_emps(50) from dual
  2  /

GET_EMPS(50)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      8060 VERREYNNE  PLUMBER         8061 08-APR-08       4000                    50
      8061 FEUERSTEIN PLUMBER         7839 27-FEB-10       4500                    50
      8085 TRICHLER   PLUMBER         8061 08-APR-10       3500                    50
      8100 PODER      PLUMBER         8061                 3750                    50


SQL>
```

This statement also runs in SQL Developer, although the result set is laid out in an *ugly* fashion.

So, if you are having problems with your function, the questions are:

1. What client environment are you using?
2. In what precise fashion does it "not work"?  Please describe the observed behaviour, including any error messages?
3. Also give us environment details such as the version of the database, the OS, etc.

---

Having read your other question on this topic I thought the problem might be due to the use of a User-Defined Ref Cursor (rather than the built-in).  However, that doesn't make any difference.  This packaged function:

```
SQL> create or replace package emp_rc_utils as
  2
  3      type emp_rc is ref cursor return emp%rowtype;
  4
  5      function       get_emps
  6          ( p_dno in emp.deptno%type
  7      )
  8      return emp_rc;
  9  end;
 10  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body emp_rc_utils as
  2
  3      function       get_emps
  4          ( p_dno in emp.deptno%type
  5      )
  6          return emp_rc
  7      is
  8          return_value emp_rc_utils.emp_rc;
  9      begin
 10
 11          open return_value for select * from emp where deptno = p_dno;
 12
 13          return return_value;
 14      end get_emps;
 15
 16  end emp_rc_utils;
 17  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

Still works...

```
SQL> declare
  2      rc sys_refcursor;
  3  begin
  4      rc := emp_rc_utils.get_emps(50);
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


SQL> select emp_rc_utils.get_emps(50) from dual
  2  /

EMP_RC_UTILS.GET_EMP
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      8085 TRICHLER   PLUMBER         8061 08-APR-10       3500                    50
      8060 VERREYNNE  PLUMBER         8061 08-APR-08       4000                    50
      8061 FEUERSTEIN PLUMBER         7839 27-FEB-10       4500                    50
      8100 PODER      PLUMBER         8061                 3750                    50


SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your posts APC but I'm new to this an I don't understand what you are suggesting I should do

Comment: Mostly you need to give more details of what you're doing now and exactly how it's failing. APC has shown that it works in principal so you need to give us enough information to help you figure out where it's going wrong.

Comment: @user521180 - My point is: what you are trying to do *ought* to work.  Hence, if you're getting an error it must be *something specific to your implementation*.  You need to go back to your code and figure it out.  Or post more details here, so we can spot it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a refcursor call or populate a user defined table and return it as follows:

```
create or replace
function getRef return sys_refcursor
is
l_ref  sys_refcursor;
begin

    open l_ref for
    select 1 a, 'a' c from dual
    union all
    select 2 a, 'b' c from dual
    union all
    select 3 a, 'c' c from dual
    union all
    select 4 a, 'd' c from dual;

    return l_ref;

end getRef;
/

select getref() from dual;

GETREF() 
-------- 
A                      C  
---------------------- -  
1                      a  
2                      b  
3                      c  
4                      d  

--you'll notice this isn't the most user-friendly result set if you look at it in SQL Developer or whatno
--drop function getRef;
```

you can also use the 'table' if you are passing back a table collection as such

```
create or replace type lookup_row as 
  object ( a number, c varchar2(20) );
  /
create or replace type lookups_tab as 
  table of lookup_row;
/

create or replace
function getUserDefinedTableType return lookups_tab
is
lTestTypeTable  lookups_tab;
begin

     SELECT lookup_row(a,c)
               bulk collect INTO lTestTypeTable
               from
    (select 1 a, 'a' c from dual
    union all
    select 2 a, 'b' c from dual
    union all
    select 3 a, 'c' c from dual
    union all
    select 4 a, 'd' c from dual);

    return lTestTypeTable;

end getUserDefinedTableType;
/


select * from table(getUserDefinedTableType());
--this returns it in a more user friendly manner
--http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/network/2003/01/22/feuerstein.html?page=2
--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150137/converting-oracle-query-into-user-defined-types-in-pl-sql/3152885#3152885
A                      C                    
---------------------- -------------------- 
1                      a                    
2                      b                    
3                      c                    
4                      d
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what these two solutions are and what theyre doing.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
myCursor := package_name.function_name(param,param);
```

this would have to be from within a test block or a stored procedure.